# Iterating over unique elements of `std::multiset`

Tags: c++, c++11, multiset

All I need is to know if something exists and how many times it exist. I will iterate over the existent things and query how much of that exists.

My implementation so far uses `multiset`, I do as follow:

```
std::multiset<thing> a;
auto previous = a.end();
for( auto each = a.begin(); each != a.end(); ++each ) {
    if( previous == a.end() || *previous != *each ) {
        a.count(*each);
    }
    previous = each;
}
```

## Clarifications

I have a vector of `thing`s. But they repeat the value sometimes, I want to iterate over unique  `thing`s and for each unique do something. This "something" needs to know the amount of time this `thing` appears on the vector.

The code I posted above is how I am resolving my problem right now, it does not seems to be the most elegant way to do what I want.

I am just following the Stackoverflow guidelines: I tell what is my problem, and I tell my (tried) solution.

If a sentence with a question mark is really needed, there you go: Is there a way to iterate over unique elements over a `multiset`?

Comment: **what** are you trying to do again?

Comment: Just use `.count` *only*? If it exists, you get back how many times. If not, you get back `0`.

Comment: The problem with `.count` only surely is that you don't know what to call it on until you have iterated through the set.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan What I want to know is described in the first paragraph. The others paragraphs show how I am doing that by now.

Comment: Edited my question for clarifications, please re-read it

Comment: There is a way requiring less code (create a temporary collection with `std::unique` and iterate through that), but it's certainly less efficient and only really saves one line! I don't think the STL provides a ready-made solution for your problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Three possible approaches:

- Use `std::unique` to create a temporary collection of unique values. This might make the code a little more readable, but less efficient.
- Advance your iterator by using `std::multiset::upper_bound` rather than increments: `for( auto each = a.begin(); each != a.end(); each=a.upper_bound(*each))` - that way you don't need the `if` check insider your loop, plus it is guaranteed to be **logarithmic in size**. Pretty cool (didn't know that before I looked it up). For the following suggestion, all credit goes to **@MarkRansom**: Using `std::upper_bound` from `<algorithm>`, you can specify a range in which to look for the upper bound. In your case, you already have a good candidate for the start of that range, so this method is likely to be more efficient, depending on the implementation in your standard library.
- If this is a real performance problem for you and the previous solution still isn't good enough, consider switching to `map<thing, unsigned>` or even `unordered_map<thing,unsigned>` where the `unsigned` just keeps track of the number of equivalent `thing`s you have. That implies rewriting your insertion/deletion code though.

Comment: upper_bound is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AndréPuel if the average number of repeats in the `multiset` are expected to be small, the free form of `upper_bound` might be faster than the member function since you specify the start of the search. P.S. I think there's a typo, `*it` should be `*each`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, very helpful! I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: AIUI `std::unique` can't be applied to a `std::multiset` though it is possible to simply iterate over the multiset into a set.

Answer (score 0):

Use equal_range (defined in multiset) in a while loop.